# How do obtain the NSString equivalent for an array of chars in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsstring, char

More specifically, I put a breakpoint in my code after 
`NSString *signStr = [NSString stringWithCString:text encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];`
I am calling the function with `secret= @"12345678901234567890"` and `movingFactor = 1`
I noticed that at the breakpoint, `signStr` is an empty string,
also are there any other noticeable errors in the code?
Thanks

```
-(NSString*) generateOTP:(NSString*) secret with:(uint64_t) movingFactor
{
    NSString* result;

    const int DIGITS = 6;
    const int SIX_DIGITS = 1000000;

    char text[8];
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        text[i] = movingFactor & 0xff;
        movingFactor >>= 8;
    }

    NSString *signStr = [NSString stringWithCString:text encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSString* hash = [self sha1UseKey:secret toSign:signStr];

    int offset = [hash characterAtIndex:[hash length] - 1] & 0xf;

    int binary = (([hash characterAtIndex:offset] & 0x7f) << 24) |
        (([hash characterAtIndex:offset+1] & 0xff) << 16) |
        (([hash characterAtIndex:offset+2] & 0xff) << 8) | ([hash characterAtIndex:offset+3] & 0xff);

    int otp = binary % SIX_DIGITS;

    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", otp];

    NSString* zero = @"0";
    while ([result length] < DIGITS) {
        result = [zero stringByAppendingString:result];
    }
    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be a "C string" it has to be terminated by a zero (`'\0'`).  If `movingFactor` is 1 then the last character will be `0x01`, and the first (and every other byte) is zero due to shifting.  This makes the *first* character zero, which makes the string "empty".

Comment: So then how do I make my code work? how can I modify something by bytes and then converted it to an NSString with the same value bitwise?

Comment: Are you sure you want an NSString here? If you need to be able to store arbitrary bytes, NSData would seem like a better fit.